# Cumulative Sum per item in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have DB2 table like below -

```
Date1       Item_code    Amt
2018-06-01  1            2
2018-06-02  1            3
2018-06-03  2            4
2018-06-03  2            5
2018-06-04  3            6
2018-06-05  3            7
2018-06-06  4            8
```

I need the cumulative sum item_code wise per day. The result should look like -

```
Date1       Item_code    Amt
2018-06-01  1            2
2018-06-02  1            5
2018-06-03  2            9
2018-06-04  3            6
2018-06-05  3            13
2018-06-06  4            8
```

I have tried a lot by myself and search also on SO but nothing is fulfilling my need. There are a lot of examples if I just need the cumulative sum day wise irrespective of item code.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want aggregation with a cumulative sum:

```
select item_code, date1,
       sum(sum(amt)) over (partition by item_code order by date1) as running_amt
from t
group by item_code, date;
```

Comment: I don't think DB2 supports window function and if it supports even I do not have the facility to use them. So is there any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai . . . DB2 as sold by IBM definitely does support window functions: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_olapspecification.html.  They are called OLAP specifications.