# Generate date range for missing dates and assign the current maximum value

Tags: sql, date, db2

I have a table like below in DB2 -

```
 Date       |       Catg|      Amount
 2018-05-21 |         2 |      583227.57485
 2018-05-21 |         5 |     2200097.73226
 2018-05-22 |         2 |      116246.63551
 2018-05-22 |         4 |      231116.66241
 2018-05-22 |         5 |      244093.91680
 2018-05-31 |         1 |      244714.77015
 2018-05-31 |         2 |      288946.64734
 2018-05-31 |         3 |      330801.32189
 2018-05-31 |         5 |      345984.62256
 2018-06-05 |         4 |      228612.55653
 2018-06-05 |         5 |      244944.22519
 2018-06-11 |         2 |      288940.63303
 2018-06-11 |         3 |      344938.50723
 2018-06-11 |         4 |      346234.65196
 2018-06-11 |         5 |      375935.22568
```

I want to generate the report for the month of June till 22nd for every catg. So I want the report to be -

```
 Date       |       Catg|      Amount

 2018-06-01 |         1 |      244714.77015     -- Being 5/31 is latest for 6/1
 2018-06-01 |         2 |      288946.64734     -- Being 5/31 is latest for 6/1
 2018-06-01 |         3 |      330801.32189     -- Being 5/31 is latest for 6/1
 2018-06-01 |         4 |      231116.66241     -- Being 5/22 is latest for 6/1     
 2018-06-01 |         5 |      345984.62256     -- Being 5/31 is latest for 6/1
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 2018-06-22 |         1 |      244714.77015     -- Being 5/31 is latest for 6/22
 2018-06-22 |         2 |      288940.63303     -- Being 6/11 is latest for 6/22
 2018-06-22 |         3 |      344938.50723     -- Being 6/11 is latest for 6/22
 2018-06-22 |         4 |      346234.65196     -- Being 6/11 is latest for 6/22
 2018-06-22 |         5 |      375935.22568     -- Being 6/11 is latest for 6/22
```

I don't know if this even doable with SQL. I have successfully generated the dates but not sure how to assign the immediate previous values to them.

I have generated the dates through below code -

```
WITH DATE_TAB(DATES) AS (                
SELECT DATE('2018-06-01') DATES     
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1               
UNION ALL                           
SELECT DATES + 1 DAYS AS DATES      
FROM DATE_TAB                       
WHERE DATES < '2018-06-22')         
SELECT DATES                            
FROM DATE_TAB
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Show how you generated the dates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Ques Updated and these amounts are generated through this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51116723/cumulative-sum-per-item-in-db2/51116771

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rest-part will be `CROSS JOIN` :

```
WITH DATE_TAB(DATES) AS (                
     SELECT DATE('2018-06-01') DATES     
     FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1               
     UNION ALL                           
     SELECT DATES + 1 DAYS AS DATES      
     FROM DATE_TAB                       
     WHERE DATES < '2018-06-22'
)         
SELECT DISTINCT dt.DATES, dt1.Catg, 
       (SELECT t.Amount
        FROM table t
        WHERE t.catg = dt.catg and t.date <= dt.date
        ORDER BY t.date desc
        FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
       )                            
FROM DATE_TAB dt 
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Catg, Amount FROM table) dt1;
```

Comment: I think in inner query you meant dt1.catg. `WHERE t.catg = dt.catg and t.date <= dt.date`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
with date_tab ( . . . )
select d.dte, c.catg, 
       (select t.amount
        from t
        where t.catg = c.catg and t.dte <= d.dte
        order by t.dte desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as amount
from date_tab d cross join
     (select distinct catg from t) c
order by d.dte, c.catg;
```

Comment: You must be from another planet.